# Use pandas to combine/merge parent table with child table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a parent table `df0`, with two levels code `Code1`, `Code2`, and `Message`. Multiple child tables as `df1` which stores lower level `Code2` and `Messages`. As you can see, `"df1"` is indicated as index in table `df0`.

```py
    import pandas as pd

    s1 = pd.Series([1, 0, 'A'])
    s2 = pd.Series([2, 'df1', 'B'])
    s3 = pd.Series([3, 0, 'C'])
    df0 = pd.DataFrame([list(s1), list(s2), list(s3)],  columns =  ["Code1", "Code2", "Message"])

    df0   

         Code1  Code2   Message
    0     1     0       A
    1     2     df1     B
    2     3     0       C

    s4 = pd.Series([0, 'B1'])
    s5 = pd.Series([1, 'B2'])
    s6 = pd.Series([2, 'B3'])
    df1 = pd.DataFrame([list(s4), list(s5), list(s6)],  columns =  ["Code2", "Message"])


    df1
                Code2   Message
        0       0       B1
        1       1       B2
        2       2       B3
```

I want to have a larger table essential put `df1` back to `df0` and make a flat merged table. Thank you for your help.

```py
        Code1   Code2   Message
0       1       0       A
1       2               B
2       2       0       B1
3       2       1       B2
4       2       2       B3
5       3       0       C
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `merge`.  The below provides an intermediate result that can be further processed to obtain the desired output.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
print(pd.__version__)

s1 = pd.Series([1, 0, 'A'])
s2 = pd.Series([2, 'df1', 'B'])
s3 = pd.Series([3, 0, 'C'])
df0 = pd.DataFrame([list(s1), list(s2), list(s3)],  columns =  ["Code1", "Code2", "Message"])

s4 = pd.Series([0, 'B1'])
s5 = pd.Series([1, 'B2'])
s6 = pd.Series([2, 'B3'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame([list(s4), list(s5), list(s6)],  columns =  ["Code2", "Message"])
join_key = 'df1'
df1[join_key] = join_key

df2 = pd.concat([df0[df0['Code2'] == join_key], df1], sort=True)

result = df0.merge(df2, left_on=['Code2'], right_on=['df1'], how='outer', suffixes=('_l', '_r'))
print (result)
```

Result

```
0.24.2
   Code1_l Code2_l Message_l  Code1_r Code2_r Message_r  df1
0      1.0       0         A      NaN     NaN       NaN  NaN
1      3.0       0         C      NaN     NaN       NaN  NaN
2      2.0     df1         B      NaN       0        B1  df1
3      2.0     df1         B      NaN       1        B2  df1
4      2.0     df1         B      NaN       2        B3  df1
5      NaN     NaN       NaN      2.0     df1         B  NaN
```

Comment: Please note that `"df1"` row from the original table `df0` is retained.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. The trick would then be to grab the rows from the parent table that are used in the join and append them to the child table.  This has the effect of carrying that row along to the resultant dataframe.  Update answer reflecting this strategy.